# citing author in unsrt

Tags: citing, natbib

I am trying to execute the code below. For `\citeauthor{}`, I am getting (**author?**). Could you please let me know how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{tomesh2020coreset} used dimensionality reduction technique called
coreset to faithfully represent the big data with limited number of points and then ap-
plied VQA to train ML models

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

Following bibtex is saved in a different file.

```
@article{tomesh2020coreset,
      title={Coreset Clustering on Small Quantum Computers}, 
      author={Teague Tomesh and Pranav Gokhale and Eric R. Anschuetz and Frederic T. Chong},
      year={2020},
      journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1703.06476},
      eprint={2004.14970},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={quant-ph}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the `\citeauthor` command is not defined in the LaTeX kernel. If the code you show above does not throw an error message about an "unknown command \citeauthor", it must be the case that you're loading a package that defines a macro called `\citeauthor`. My guess is that your real document loads the `natbib` package, either explicitly or via a setting in the document class you employ.

Second, the ancient `unsrt` bib style can only produce numeric style citation call-outs. Moreover, it doesn't set aside enough meta information for each entry for `natbib`'s `\citeauthor` command to work; that's why `\citeauthor` produces "(**author?**)". What's the remedy? You need to use a more modern bibliography style, e.g., `unsrtnat` or `elsarticle-num`.

Third, admittedly off-topic, you shouldn't use the `@article` entry type for pieces that have been submitted to Arxiv. I suggest you employ the `@misc` entry type and switch the `journal` field to `howpublished`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % to keep everything on a single page %% {report}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybibfile.bib}
@misc{tomesh2020coreset,
      title={Coreset Clustering on Small Quantum Computers}, 
      author={Teague Tomesh and Pranav Gokhale and 
              Eric R. Anschuetz and Frederic T. Chong},
      year={2020},
      howpublished={arXiv preprint arXiv:1703.06476},
      eprint={2004.14970},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={quant-ph}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}
\citeauthor{tomesh2020coreset} used dimensionality reduction technique 
called coreset to faithfully represent the big data with 
limited number of points and then applied VQA to train ML models

\bibliography{mybibfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remark: Instead of using the `howpublished` field, you could also use the `url` field, as in `url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.14970}`.