# Problem with citing authors - showing (author ? )

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I'm trying to cite authors in an overleaf project. I would like for it to be on this format:
[image: Citing Fossen (2011) example]

However, I'm getting this:

[image: Problem illustration]

Here is my overleaf code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\def\biblio{\bibliographystyle{unsrt}\bibliography{references}}

\begin{document}
\def\biblio{references} % For making bibliography working with subfiles, prints at end of each subfile
% \maketitle
Trying to cite this author \citeauthor{fossen2011} \\
How about this \citet{fossen2011} \\ 
Alternative workaround method: \cite[Fossen (2011)]{fossen2011} 


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
% \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

And my reference.bib file:

```
<bibtex>

@book{fossen2011,
    author = {Fossen, T. I.},
    title = {Handbook of Marine Craft Hydrodynamics and Motion Control},
    publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons, Ltd},
    year = {2011},
    address = {West Sussex, United Kingdom}
}
```

Does anyone know how to get a proper citation? Appriciate any help!

Comment: Natbib and the generic unsrt.bst are incompatible. The problem has been explained in [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634293/19384)

Answer (score 0):

in my point of view it has something to do with *natbib* and the

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

You can use

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

which is *natbib*s own plain version.